# Matlab: writting dicom metadata with dynamic fieldnames

Tags: matlab, struct, eval

I'm trying to write dicom metainformations to a dicom file. Here the fieldnames are changing dynamicaly depending on the given metainformations.

```
for j = 1:obj.pln.propStf.numOfBeams
    eval(['meta.FractionGroupSequence.Item_1.ReferencedBeamSequence.Item_' num2str(j) '.ReferencedBeamNumber = j;'])
    eval(['meta.FractionGroupSequence.Item_1.ReferencedBeamSequence.Item_' num2str(j) '.BeamDoseSpecificationPoint = [j,j,j];'])
    eval(['meta.FractionGroupSequence.Item_1.ReferencedBeamSequence.Item_' num2str(j) '.BeamDose = j;'])
    eval(['meta.FractionGroupSequence.Item_1.ReferencedBeamSequence.Item_' num2str(j) '.BeamMeterset = j;'])
    eval(['meta.FractionGroupSequence.Item_1.ReferencedBeamSequence.Item_' num2str(j) '.BeamDosePointDepth = j;'])
    eval(['meta.FractionGroupSequence.Item_1.ReferencedBeamSequence.Item_' num2str(j) '.BeamDosePointSSD = j;'])
end
```

As you can see here `meta.FractionGroupSequence.Item_1.ReferencedBeamSequence.Item_' num2str(j) '.ReferencedBeamNumber = j;` the fieldnames of the struct changes dynamicaly with the amount of beams given in `obj.pln.propStf.numOfBeams`.

The Problem with this approach is, that if I'm going to try to have something like that: `eval(['meta.FractionGroupSequence.Item_1.ReferencedBeamSequence.Item_' num2str(j) '.ReferencedBeamNumber = 'TEST';'])`. The eval function tries to find the text 'TEST'.

So the question is, is there a different approach for the given problem instead of using eval?

Comment: I am confused. Yes, if you do `eval('A')` eval will try to use `A`. That is clear. Now what is your question? how to make `eval` not look for `A`? well, don't type it there? Its clear what your problem is with the code, but its not at all clear what you want _instead_. Also eval is super, super, super bad as a function,  there are always better alternatives.

Comment: In your case, a clear alternative is: `meta.FractionGroupSequence.Item_1.ReferencedBeamSequence.(['Item_' num2str(j)']).ReferencedBeamNumber = j;`

Comment: Hello @AnderBiguri Biguri, thanks for the quick response. I'am looking for an alternative of using eval. I tried sprintf instead but it gives you a String.

Comment: My second comment is an alternative to eval, you can use it as is. However, it does not solve the fact that you want a variable `TEST` to exist when it does not, which is the question that you asked.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Thank you very much, your second comment worked and was the solution! Sorry, TEST is not a variable it is text. I just forgot ''. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `eval` MATLAB allows you to access dynamic struct fields with strings:

```
mystruct.hello=1;
mystruct.('hello')=1; % equivalent.
```

just do:

```
meta.FractionGroupSequence.Item_1.ReferencedBeamSequence.(['Item_'num2str(j)']).ReferencedBeamNumber = j;
```